# My Access token is not can Follow account instagram

Tags: c#, instagram, bad-request

when i'm try to follow to any one on instagram by use my client Applcation in my account 
i'm use link to get access token and write this scope :

> https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=ID_CLIENT&scope=basic+follower_list+public_content+comments+relationships+likes&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&response_type=token

this is work to get access token

but when i try to follow any one be sent POST Webrequeste method like :

> action=follow

this is response badRequeste 400  ;

when i try get access token by this web https://apigee.com

then that is work without problem :(

Comment: your code to POST request is wrong may be

Comment: No , because when i'm use acess token for apigee.com applcation that work on my code

Comment: see what error message in response json says, it will tell u if u dont have follow permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this free [Instagram Token Generator](https://instagramtoken.com) to generate an auth token with the necessary scopes. Just check the boxes for whichever scopes you need.

[image]